# Encountering 404 error for some GCP Terraform resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are getting the following error for a number of resources when trying to deploy GCP resources using Terraform. 
It reads:

> **404.** That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL `/v2/organizations/organizations/XXXXXXXXXXX/policies?>alt=json` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

Example resources are :

- google_org_policy_policy
- google_organization_policy
- google_monitoring_notification_channel

And more...

I would like to note that its not a permission issue since creating the resources above manually works flawlessly.

Me and my Team have experience with AWS on TF, but its our first time trying to build a large scale GCP project and we are very frustrated.

Any help would be very appreciated.
It happens on various provider versions , we started using latest, but we also tried older versions in jumps of 10 (we started on x.40, we tried x.30 , x.20 and x.10)

we are currently back on latest

#### Full example

```
│   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
│   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
│   <p>The requested URL <code>/v2/organizations/organizations/XXXXXXXXXXX/policies?alt=json</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
│ 
│ 
│   with google_org_policy_policy.primary,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "google_org_policy_policy" "primary":
│    5: resource "google_org_policy_policy" "primary" {
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Read on git that someone had this issue when not specifying a project_id on the provider,
We Do have a project_id mentioned in the provider, but also this is an organization wide resource.

The issue has resolved for the resource **google_org_policy_policy**
﻿by changing the parent parameter:

```
﻿﻿parent = "organizations/${data.google_organization.default.id}"
# To﻿
﻿﻿﻿﻿parent = "${data.google_organization.default.id}"\
```

Comment: This was actually very helpful, my use case was a bit different, but the idea is whether you're applying at org/folder/project scope, the Google API is expecting that `organizations/[org-id]` structure. In your case, I can see it now in your error output too, the variable substitution you were trying to do was resulting in a `organizations/organizations/[org-id]` scenario. My case was the opposite, I didn't have the word `organizations` appearing at all, just the actual org-id directly.